# Can't add TextView to LinearLayout

Tags: android

I'm doing summer lab assignment for my Android class.

In layout_main.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/main_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:name="tests.tinyplanner.ActivityFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In main_menu.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <tests.tinyplanner.ThemeButton
        android:id="@+id/todoButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/todo_button_title" />

    <tests.tinyplanner.ThemeButton
        android:id="@+id/calendarButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calendar_button_title" />

    <tests.tinyplanner.ThemeButton
        android:id="@+id/notesButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/notes_button_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For layout_main.xml I have a class:

```
package tests.tinyplanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private View todoButton;
    private View calendarButton;
    private View notesButton;

    private LayoutInflater inflater_;
    private View inflateView_;

    private void doInflate(Context context) {
        this.inflater_ = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.inflateView_ = this.inflater_.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, this);

        this.todoButton = this.inflateView_.findViewById(R.id.todoButton);
        this.calendarButton = this.inflateView_.findViewById(R.id.calendarButton);
        this.notesButton = this.inflateView_.findViewById(R.id.notesButton);

    }

    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.doInflate(context);
    }

    public MainLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public View getTodoButton() {
        return  this.todoButton;
    }

    public View getCaldendarButton() {
        return  this.calendarButton;
    }

    public View getNotesButton() {
        return  this.notesButton;
    }
}
```

I use this layout in MainActivity

```
this.layout = new MainLayout(this);
TextView logoTextView = (TextView)((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.logo_layout, null);
((MainLayout) this.layout).addView(logoTextView);
this.setContentView(this.layout);
this.todoButton = ((MainLayout)this.layout).getTodoButton();
this.todoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
this.calendarButton = ((MainLayout)this.layout).getCaldendarButton();
this.calendarButton.setOnClickListener(this);
this.notesButton = ((MainLayout)this.layout).getNotesButton();
this.notesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

All buttons are displayed correctly. The problem is that `logoTextView` is not displayed at all. `logo_layout` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/logo_title"
    android:id="@+id/logoTextView"
    android:theme="@style/LogoTheme"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TextView>
```

LogoTheme is like this:

> ```
> <style name="LogoTheme">
>     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
>     <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorFontButtonDefault</item>
>     <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
>     <item name="android:ems">80</item>
>     <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
>     <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
>     <item name="android:textAlignment" tools:targetApi="17">center</item>
> </style>
> ```

Why is `logoTextView` not displayed?

Comment: What's under "@style/LogoTheme" ?

Comment: Edited my question to add info about LogoTheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things went wrong in your code. Before jumping into it, let me clear some concept

1) By default, orientation for Linear layout will be Horizontal. It means that all child view will be stack horizontally inside linear layout based on width defined for each child.

```
  |   ChildA    |   ChildB |  ChildC  |
```

2) If Any one child defines width as "MATCH_PARENT" then it will not allow to show other child underneath it, just like below

```
  | ChildA                             | (Not visible) childB | (Not visible) childC|
```

**Based on this information, Let try to understand your issue**

**First thing:** Inside MainActivity, where you try to create a MainLayout, you need to specify Orientation for MainLayout

```
this.layout = new MainLayout(this);
((MainLayout)this.layout).setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

This will allow to stack all children vertically so that we can see all children

**Second thing:**, Inside layout_main.xml, please define layout_height of Linear layout as "wrap_content". This will allow your logotext to be seen on screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/main_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:name="tests.tinyplanner.ActivityFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: (Why need to add orientation even though setting it from XML)

Lets check how MainLayout is created. First we created instance of MainLayout inside Activity. which in turn call doInflatelayout() inside main layout.

By doing so what we are doing is, we create a linear layout and inside inflate new linear layout (with orientation set from XML)

By looking at the View Hierarchy:

> MainLayout (Parent)
>
> > LinearLayout (with Orientation inside XML)
> >
> > > Linear Layout ( with ThemeButton and Orientation set from XML)

Now You have Orientation set for first child of MainLayout. But you are not setting orientation for MainLayout.

So we need to set Orientation for MainLayout when we create it.

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I just can't understand one thing. In XML file I already made the orientation vertical. Why does it need to set the orientation again using `((MainLayout)this.layout).setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: I updated above Answer in order to explain your concerns. I hope this is answering your question. Let me know if you have any further question